# Conditional Check in Where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

i have a procedure in which the below condition is to be written in a WHERE clause. How do I do that.

itemid is a parameter which can be null.

if itemid is available then add it to my where clause,else do nothing

Comment: if you want people to help you first help them understand your problem. what do you mean by "it's not working" ? what is full query?

Comment: if ItemID is NULL then it should not fetch any rows? or should it fetch the rownum between Row_Start and Row_End?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some people use this technique

```
... WHERE @itemid IS NULL OR tbl.itemid = @itemid
```

It guarantees though that you will never get an index seek on the itemid column.

A better approach if the table is at all big is to split the query up into 2 separate cases

```
IF(@itemid IS NULL)
  SELECT foo FROM bar
ELSE
  SELECT foo FROM bar WHERE itemid = @itemid
```

If the number of combinations is too large you can consider dynamic SQL. Be sure you understand SQL injection first.

Ref: [Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL](http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html)

Comment: Are you sure that index itemid not used if we have `@itemid IS NULL OR tbl.itemid = @itemid`. According tour tests, its using indexes. Maybe your answer is too old?

Answer (score 2):

e.g.

```
SELECT Something
FROM SomeTable
WHERE (@MyParam IS NULL OR SomeField = @MyParam)
    AND AnotherField = 1
```

You'll want to test this in your specific scenario for performance. If it's a simple query i.e. without a lot of conditional parameters, you might want to try this instead for performance:

```
IF ( @MyParam IS NULL )
    SELECT Something
    FROM SomeTable
    WHERE AnotherField = 1
ELSE
    SELECT Something
    FROM SomeTable
    WHERE SomeField = @MyParam 
        AND AnotherField = 1
```