# Best way to make search sql query for variable number of parameters

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conditional Check in Where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3447980/conditional-check-in-where-clause)

I have a few parameters that I can provide in order to search data from table:

```
- DateFrom
- DateTo
- Name
- TypeId
```

I have one code that I need to improve. In application code I have a function that get all this parameters and based on what parameters that I provide by using IF statements I build different queries.
I wonder is there better way to do this?
To make just one query with parameters and if there is no parameter ignore it.
So I don't have to do this:

```
select...where DateFrom = 'someDate'
select...where DateFrom = 'someDate' and DateTo = 'someDate'
select...where DateFrom = 'someDate' and DateTo = 'someDate' and Name = 'someName'
etc.
```

Comment: duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate of a duplicate... read the best text on the matter: Dynamic Search Conditions in T-SQL, by Erland Sommarskog: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the very simple approach, assuming your parameters have the names @Begin, @End, @Name:

```
select...
where 
    (@Begin IS NULL OR DateFrom = @Begin) 
and (@End is NULL OR DateTo = @End)
and (@Name is NULL OR Name = @Name)
...
```

Then if you pass the parameter's value as NULL - then query will skip it

Comment: since the OP is using SQL Server 2008, `OPTION(RECOMPILE)` can most likely be used (depending on the exact SQL Server sub version: http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search-2008.html#SPandCUs) which can resolve the local variables at runtime and basically remove the `OR`s and utilize an index if there is one.

Answer (score 0):

Use a common util class to control it.

`getSqlParams(String dateFrom)`
`getSqlParams(String dataFrom,DateTo)`

and so on. maybe can help you.because different params means diffrent dimension.
Using If is really so ugly. :(